# Need some help understanding for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

could someone help me with the logic behind the code below

assuming that **mpg is a list of dictionaries**

```
cylinders = set(d['cyl'] for d in mpg)
```

I wrote this code but I'm looking for some help to summarize it in one line

```
cylinders=list()
for d in mpg :
    cylinders.append(d['cyl'])

new_cylinders=set(cylinders)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Those two snippets do the same thing.  For every dictionary in `mpg`, it adds the value of the `'cyl'` key to that list/set.

Comment: The first line of code is equivalent to the second block of code, and therefore summarizes it in one line. The second block of code is equivalent to the first and therefore expresses the logic of the first in more expansive terms.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does an example make it clear?

```
mpg = [ {'make':'Ford','cyl':12}, {'make':'Toyota','cyl':9}, {'make':'Rolls Royce','cyl':16} ]
```

After your function, you would have:

```
new_cylinders = {12, 9, 16}
```

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts , Thanks for your answer, I know how the output looks like but what seems confusing to me, is that no **.add()** is included and how it keeps a record of previous **d['cyl']** s. I also attempted to print all the *d['cyl']*s in that way(one-line for loop) but it sent traceback, Could you please show me how to do that if it is possible?

Comment: In the "for" loop you have above, if you replace the `cylinders.append` line with `print( d["cyl"] )`, I guarantee it will work.

Comment: I meant how to make changes in `cylinders = set(d['cyl'] for d in mpg)`, sorry if I couldn't convey my purpose properly.

Comment: Given a set, you can do `print( ', '.join(str(c) for c in cylinders) )`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing inside `set(...)` is called a *[generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator-expression)*. When occurring "naked", they need to be surrounded by parentheses, but when they occur as the single parameter of a function call, the parentheses may be omitted.

A generator expression returns a *generator*, which is a thing that, on demand, will produce a sequence of values. In this case, the `set()` function will do the demanding and build a set out the the result. (So the reason that you do not need an explicit `.add`, is that you are providing a sequence of values to build the set from.)

(I think you could also use a *[set display](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-set-display)* and write `cylinders = {d['cyl'] for d in mpg}`)

So how do you print things inside the generator expression? Well, the thing before `for` has to be a single expression; something that generates exactly one value. You could do it using an auxiliary function:

```
def print_and_return(x):
    print(x)
    return x

cyls = set(print_and_return(d['cyl']) for d in mpg)
```